# Is/was there such a function as cudaMalloc2DArray()?

Tags: cuda, textures

While reading the book "*The CUDA Handbook: A Comprehensive Guide to GPU Programming*", I came across a confusion: In a table on section "**10.13.2**" there is a function called `cudaMalloc2DArray()` to allocate memory for a CUDA array. Is it just a simple mistake or a deprecated function which is not available in recent CUDA versions?

***PS***. I can't find `cudaMalloc2DArray()` on Nvidia's related CUDA references.

***EDIT***: My question is not about how to allocate 2D Array. Since it's a well known book and widely used by beginners around the world (also I have seen lectures and PPTs based on this book), I thought it's a good place to find out whether it's a mistake or just an obsolete function.

Comment: I found out that the author of this book  "ArchaeaSoftware (Nicholas Wilt)" is here in SO. @ArchaeaSoftware .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AnderBiguri described what you *should* do. For historical reference, though - the answer is **No, there wasn't a 2D version of this function** - at least not in any CUDA version since 2.3. See:

http://dirac.ruc.dk/manuals/cuda-2.3/CUDA_ReferenceManual_2.3.pdf

That site has the CUDA documentation in PDF for multiple older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, you can use `cudaMalloc3DArray()` for 2D arrays. [According to the docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g948143cf2423a072ac6a31fb635efd88):

> `cudaMalloc3DArray()` can allocate the following:
>
> - [...]
> - A 2D array is allocated if only the depth extent is zero.
> - [...]

I am unsure if its a typo or the 2D version existed before.